KeyStroke.getKeyCode(int keyCode, int modifiers) returns KeyStrokes with missing character values
Am I doing something wrong? I'm trying to create a simple app that displays the keys of the selected keyboard when users are using input methods for foreign keyboards. (This is probably more useful for developers than users, but users who need to switch languages will also find it useful.) To do this, I need to be able to get the character for each key code. The KeyStroke class has a method that should do this: KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(int keyCode, int modifiers). Unfortunately, every time I call it, the returned KeyStroke's value for its getKeyChar always returns 0xFFFF. Here's the method to test this:
public void showKeys() {
  Field[] fields = KeyEvent.class.getDeclaredFields();
  Map<Integer, Field> fieldMap = new TreeMap<>();
  for (Field f : fields) {
    if ((f.getType() == Integer.TYPE) && f.getName().startsWith("VK")) {
      try {
        int value = (Integer) f.get(null);
        fieldMap.put(value, f);
      } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Should not happen", e);
      }
    }
  }
  for (int value = 44; value <= 90; ++value) {
    Field field = fieldMap.get(value);
    if (field != null) {
      // Setting the last parameter to false, or leaving it off, gives me the same thing.
      KeyStroke keyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(value, 0, true);
      final char keyChar = keyStroke.getKeyChar();
      final int keyCode = keyStroke.getKeyCode();
      System.out.printf("%6d: %-30s -- %5d = 0x%04X: %c (0x%04X)%n",
          value, field.getName(), keyCode, keyCode, keyChar, (int) keyChar);
    }
  }
}

Running this method prints this:
44: VK_COMMA                       --    44 = 0x002C: Ôøø (0xFFFF)
45: VK_MINUS                       --    45 = 0x002D: Ôøø (0xFFFF)
46: VK_PERIOD                      --    46 = 0x002E: Ôøø (0xFFFF)
47: VK_SLASH                       --    47 = 0x002F: Ôøø (0xFFFF)
48: VK_0                           --    48 = 0x0030: Ôøø (0xFFFF)
49: VK_1                           --    49 = 0x0031: Ôøø (0xFFFF)
50: VK_2                           --    50 = 0x0032: Ôøø (0xFFFF)
51: VK_3                           --    51 = 0x0033: Ôøø (0xFFFF)
52: VK_4                           --    52 = 0x0034: Ôøø (0xFFFF)
53: VK_5                           --    53 = 0x0035: Ôøø (0xFFFF)
54: VK_6                           --    54 = 0x0036: Ôøø (0xFFFF)
55: VK_7                           --    55 = 0x0037: Ôøø (0xFFFF)
56: VK_8                           --    56 = 0x0038: Ôøø (0xFFFF)
57: VK_9                           --    57 = 0x0039: Ôøø (0xFFFF)
59: VK_SEMICOLON                   --    59 = 0x003B: Ôøø (0xFFFF)
61: VK_EQUALS                      --    61 = 0x003D: Ôøø (0xFFFF)
65: VK_A                           --    65 = 0x0041: Ôøø (0xFFFF)
66: VK_B                           --    66 = 0x0042: Ôøø (0xFFFF)
67: VK_C                           --    67 = 0x0043: Ôøø (0xFFFF)
68: VK_D                           --    68 = 0x0044: Ôøø (0xFFFF)
69: VK_E                           --    69 = 0x0045: Ôøø (0xFFFF)
70: VK_F                           --    70 = 0x0046: Ôøø (0xFFFF)
71: VK_G                           --    71 = 0x0047: Ôøø (0xFFFF)
72: VK_H                           --    72 = 0x0048: Ôøø (0xFFFF)
73: VK_I                           --    73 = 0x0049: Ôøø (0xFFFF)
74: VK_J                           --    74 = 0x004A: Ôøø (0xFFFF)
75: VK_K                           --    75 = 0x004B: Ôøø (0xFFFF)
76: VK_L                           --    76 = 0x004C: Ôøø (0xFFFF)
77: VK_M                           --    77 = 0x004D: Ôøø (0xFFFF)
78: VK_N                           --    78 = 0x004E: Ôøø (0xFFFF)
79: VK_O                           --    79 = 0x004F: Ôøø (0xFFFF)
80: VK_P                           --    80 = 0x0050: Ôøø (0xFFFF)
81: VK_Q                           --    81 = 0x0051: Ôøø (0xFFFF)
82: VK_R                           --    82 = 0x0052: Ôøø (0xFFFF)
83: VK_S                           --    83 = 0x0053: Ôøø (0xFFFF)
84: VK_T                           --    84 = 0x0054: Ôøø (0xFFFF)
85: VK_U                           --    85 = 0x0055: Ôøø (0xFFFF)
86: VK_V                           --    86 = 0x0056: Ôøø (0xFFFF)
87: VK_W                           --    87 = 0x0057: Ôøø (0xFFFF)
88: VK_X                           --    88 = 0x0058: Ôøø (0xFFFF)
89: VK_Y                           --    89 = 0x0059: Ôøø (0xFFFF)
90: VK_Z                           --    90 = 0x005A: Ôøø (0xFFFF)

All the key characters are 0xFFFF.
There's another way to get the text of a key from the key code in the KeyEvent class, which is to call its getKeyText(int keyCode) method. Unfortunately, this only works for English. When I specify an input method for a language like Japanese (boolean success = InputContext.getInstance().selectInputMethod(new Locale("ja")) I still get all the English names.
Am I doing something wrong? Or is this a bug in the method?
(I should note that there are two methods I can call. One takes a third parameter, which is boolean. Neither method works. Also, I've looped through all the fields in class KeyStroke, and they all do the same thing.)


you wrote getKeyStroke(int keyCode, int modifiers) but code is using getKeyStroke(value, 0, true); 2) there are more methods like getKeyStroke(char, int) or getKeyStroke(Character, int) ...


... javadoc: "KeyStrokes can correspond to only a press or release of a particular key, just as KEY_PRESSED and KEY_RELEASED KeyEvents do; alternately, they can correspond to typing a specific Java character, just as KEY_TYPED KeyEvents do." -- there is a difference depending of its event type

( sorry only handling the 0xFFFF returned value problem - a KeyStroke can not represent both event types {having key code and char together} - not sure how to get the keyboard layout/mapping, this is probably not done by Java, but by the op. system )

Much like a KeyEvent, a KeyStroke can either represent a key typed event, or a key press/release event.  And just like KeyEvents, a typed event has a character value but no key code, while a press or release event has a key code but no character value.  What you’re observing is normal and expected.

From the javadoc of KeyEvent

Virtual key codes do not identify a physical key: they depend on the platform and keyboard layout. For example, the key that generates VK_Q when using a U.S. keyboard layout will generate VK_A when using a French keyboard layout.

From this, what you try to achieve can't work the way you try.

You have told the OP that his implementation will not succeed but how does that help him to resolve his problem?

You are right, and I thought about it. I would have just added a comment but as a new contributor I couldn't. At least I hope to explain why the given approach doesn't work. I am myself not sure how to approach this without somehow emulating every single keyboard key being typed once, recording the input. And well - if you don't know what keys are available on the keyboard, no idea how to simulate pressing them.
